# Tor and Flatness of finite type modules in local rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, flatness

We know that a finitely presented module over a local ring $(R,m)$ is free if and only if it is flat if and only if
$$\text{Tor}_1(M, R/m)=0$$
We know that a finitely generated module is flat over the local ring $(R,m)$ if and only if it is free.
Do we still have the equivalence with $\text{Tor}_1(M, R/m)=0$?
If not, does one know a counterexample (obviously where $m$ is not of finite type)?

Comment: @user26857 yes thank you, but obviously I would like to deal with the non-noetherian case which is not immediately clear for me

Comment: Let $R$ be a valuation ring with maximal ideal $m$ satisfying $m=m^2$. Set $M=R/m$. Then $\text{Tor}_1(M, R/m)=0$; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437800/computing-operatornametor-1rr-i-r-j). On the other side $M$ is not torsion-free, hence not flat.

Comment: @user26857 why is Tor zero here ?

Comment: Did you follow the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R$ be a valuation ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ satisfying $\mathfrak m=\mathfrak m^2$. Set $M=R/\mathfrak m$. Then $\mathrm{Tor}_1(M,R/\mathfrak m)=0$; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437800). On the other side $M$ is not torsion-free, hence not flat.